# Google Maps API: setCenter using search keyword?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm using Google Maps API on my ASP.NET Web Application.

Currently the center position is set using Lat/Long values like:

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<%=MapLat %>, <%=MapLong %>), <%=MapZoomLevel %>);
```

I want the user to be able to search the map by specifying an address keyword (postcode etc).

Is it possible to set `setCenter()` using an address keyword, rather than specifying Lat/Long values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at geocoding https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

What you basically do is send the address to Google and it returns the correct Lat/Long for you.